# Failed to connect MySQL RDS instance with Springboot application to create .jar file

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have created an RDS instance of the database that I want to connect with my springboot application. The "Publicly accessible" option is set to "Yes" and I've also added inbound and outbound rules for all IPs to access the database. But I'm getting errors when I run mvn install.

`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Here is the application.properties file:

```
# datasource configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://database-1.cem1nmqwwcw4.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/twtappdb?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Pass#1234
# port customization
server.port=5000

#Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I also tried to connect to the database from MySQL workbench which is showing the error as:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNYjd.png)

Here are the inbound and outbound rules:

[inbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXIPu.png)

[outbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0MNg.png)

Am I doing something wrong in adding the security group rules?

[rds security groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJrNw.png)

Comment: can you please share RDS security groups as well?

Comment: yes sure, I've added them in the post now

Comment: Your application is hosted on EC2? also which port is allowed in RDS security group?

Comment: I've not deployed the application to EC2 yet. The security group "sg-03fc5eb1583a12fc8" is the one for RDS right? It allows all ports.

Comment: Ok so for now you are connecting with MySQLWorkbench?

Comment: yes for now I'm just connecting to mysql workbench but even that is not working

Comment: In RDS security group inbound can you please allow IP 0.0.0.0/0 (not recommended for production apps) for RDS port 3306 and try again?

Answer (score 1):

If you configure your inbound rules correctly, you can connect from MySQL Workbench to an Amazon RDS instance. I have a MySQL instance running.

Login with Workbench:

[image]

Be sure to correctly specify the hostname of the RDS instance, the user name and password.

Once you make sure inbound rules are properly setup, and you specify the correct values in MySQL Workbench, you can connect and query your data.

[image]

I do not know what else can be different from what you are doign and what I have done to successfully connect.